# Router in front of patch panel doesn't work, yet it works behind the panel

Tags: electrical-panel, switch, ethernet, data-wiring, internet

I have a strange situation here with my router and my patch panel.
After years of using it perfectly over WiFi I decided to connect it to the patch panel to wire my desktop. I observe 2 different behaviors depending on whether I plug the router before or after the patch panel.

- Case 1: Modem > Router > Patch Panel > (in room) Desktop (No internet through the room Ethernet outlet, yet WiFi/Internet remain strong)
- Case 2: Modem > Patch panel > (in room) Router > Desktop (Everything works as it should)

I wanted to patch all my rooms, but with this setup (case2) I can't.
I have tried to switch cables, bought new ones, I am at lost. Any idea why placing the router in front of/behind the patch panel is a breaker?

Comment: Can you please post pictures of your patch panel and the two setups, with wiring positioned so it can be followed in each picture?

Comment: You're connecting the Ethernet out of the modem to one of the LAN ports on the router, not the WAN port—correct?  And connecting one of the LAN ports to the patch panel?

Comment: Either the router is incredibly old and does not do auto-crossover, so it's sensitive to straight .vs. crossed cables, (but the modem out port does auto crossover) or you're plugging something in wrong, at a guess.

Comment: @Huesmann correct wiring depends if this is actually a router being used as a **router**, or a router being used as a **wireless access point** only. The latter case is also subject to needing some settings internally adjusted as a router is not normally set up to let traffic go to another router by default, so it will try to send out DHCP addresses that say it is the gateway... One of many reasons I prefer a router with no WAP functions and WAPs with no router functions.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yeah, it's not clear what the actually OP has.  I wonder if he's got DHCP functioning on modem *and* router or something.

Comment: Is this really a Home Improvement question? I know the line between wiring and routing is fuzzy, but...

Comment: It's probably more in the wheelhouse of superuser.com  which includes home networking, if looking to migrate it. Utterly forbidden at Network Engineering

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's got nothing to do with DIY Home Improvement.

Comment: Case 1 is correct, you have wired or configured it incorrectly.  Try asking on superuser, but please post more information.

Comment: @RohitGupta Case 1 or 2 makes (or should make) no difference whatsoever.Patch panel, cable through wall, etc. is simply an extension. As long as each segment stays under 100 meters it just doesn't matter. Unless there is a bad/broken/miswired cable.

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot to post my solution.

Turns out to be a hardware issue, for some reason the RJ45 that feed the computer can be a bit loose when plugged in the wall plug (issue I don't have with other cables). 
Since the plug is behind a sofa, whenever someone sat on it, it could nudge the cable and disconnect it. 

So I secure the plug with good old tape, so far so good.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2):

Older Ethernet connections only used 4 wires (1, 2, 3, 6) of the standard 8-wire cable. This allowed for some useful things such as using the inner pair (4, 5) for a phone line or using splitters to get two separate Ethernet connections on a single 8-pair cable.

However, *generally speaking*, Gigabit Ethernet (as opposed to 10 Megabit and 100 Megabit) needs 4 pairs, as does (generally, not always) Power over Ethernet. One possible situation is that your patch panel is only connecting 2 pairs, or is connecting all 4 pairs but with something miswired, and that your desktop computer Ethernet port, or possibly the router LAN Ethernet ports (but unlikely, since WAN and LAN ports should be wired up pretty much the same, and the WAN port works) simply doesn't handle a 2-pair or miswired 4-pair connection very well. In theory any Gigabit network port should downgrade to 100 Megabit if is connected to a 2-pair connection, but that doesn't always work for a variety of hardware, software, configuration and wiring reasons.

So get a tester [like this example from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3OAS7iJ):

[image: Ethernet Tester]

and see what your patch panel actually connects.

Comment: @brhans Oops! I didn't double-check and was writing from memory. You're right.